y axis scale ticks for small decimal value in Vegalite
I am trying to create a chart in vegaLite having dual axis. Issue is that, the second y axis value are in decimal, if i do not use format for  second y axis, then it simply makes format with 4 decimal digits. But i need upto 3 decimal digits after the point.

If i use format ("format":"0.3f") then it looks like a repetitive value on the y-axis

The desired view i need is only with 3 decimal values after point and non repetitive.

i am setting maxDomain second y axis values on the basis of dynamic data values (10% extra of  max value of the field. It is  dynamically pre calculatd  )  without use of values:[] .
how ??
Editor link

Your domainMax isn't large enough. Why would your domain show 0.002 when your domainMax only goes to 0.0011?
Try adding a tickCount and increasing your domainMax:

{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "background": {"expr": "BackgroundCanvasColor"},
  "config": {
    "axis": {
      "labelFontStyle": {"expr": "AxisLabelFontStyle"},
      "titleFontStyle": {"expr": "AxisTitleFontStyle"}
    },
    "font": {"expr": "FontType"},
    "legend": {
      "labelFontStyle": {"expr": "LegendLabelFontStyle"},
      "labelLimit": {"expr": "LegendLabelLimit"},
      "layout": {"top": {"anchor": "midivisionle"}},
      "orient": {"expr": "LegendOrient"},
      "symbolSize": {"expr": "LineLegendSymbolSize"},
      "symbolType": {"expr": "LineLegendSymbol"}
    },
    "title": {
      "fontStyle": {"expr": "TitleFontStyle"},
      "subtitleFontStyle": {"expr": "SubtitleFontStyle"}
    }
  },
  "data": {
    "values": [
      {"description_data": "ROW1", "division": 3, "subdivision": 0.001},
      {"description_data": "ROW2", "division": 3, "subdivision": 0.001},
      {"description_data": "ROW3", "division": 3, "subdivision": 0.001},
      {"description_data": "ROW4", "division": 2, "subdivision": 0.001},
      {"description_data": "ROW5", "division": 2, "subdivision": 0.001},
      {"description_data": "ROW6", "division": 2, "subdivision": 0.001},
      {"description_data": "ROW7", "division": 2, "subdivision": 0.001},
      {"description_data": "ROW8", "division": 2, "subdivision": 0.001},
      {"description_data": "ROW9", "division": 2, "subdivision": 0.001},
      {"description_data": "ROW10", "division": 2, "subdivision": 0.001}
    ]
  },
  "params": [
    {"name": "XAxisLabelAngle", "value": -45},
    {"name": "YAxisLabelAngle", "value": 0},
    {"name": "SubTitileColor", "value": "black"},
    {"name": "TitleFontColor", "value": "black"},
    {"name": "TitleFontSize", "value": 16},
    {"name": "TitleAlign", "value": "center"},
    {"name": "TitleText", "value": ""},
    {"name": "TitleOrient", "value": "top"},
    {"name": "TitleAnchor", "value": "midivisionle"},
    {"name": "TitleBaseline", "value": "top"},
    {"name": "TitleDx", "value": 0},
    {"name": "SubtitleFont", "value": "bold"},
    {"name": "TitleLimit", "value": 0},
    {"name": "TitleOffset", "value": 5},
    {"name": "Subtitle", "value": ""},
    {"name": "SubtitleFontSize", "value": 16},
    {"name": "MarkOpacity", "value": 1},
    {"name": "XAxisPostion", "value": 0},
    {"name": "YAxisPostion", "value": 0},
    {"name": "YAxisTitle", "value": "division"},
    {"name": "XAxisTitle", "value": "ROW"},
    {"name": "YAxisLabelLimit", "value": 0},
    {"name": "SecondYAxisLabelLimit", "value": 0},
    {"name": "YAxisLabelSize", "value": 18},
    {"name": "SecondYAxisLabelSize", "value": 17},
    {"name": "XAxisLabelSize", "value": 17},
    {"name": "XAxisLabelColor", "value": "black"},
    {"name": "YAxisLabelColor", "value": "black"},
    {"name": "SecondYAxisLabelColor", "value": "black"},
    {"name": "XAxisTickSize", "value": 10},
    {"name": "YAxisTickSize", "value": 10},
    {"name": "SecondYAxisTickSize", "value": 4},
    {"name": "BarLegendSymbolSize", "value": 0},
    {"name": "LineLegendSymbolSize", "value": 0},
    {"name": "YAxisTitleColor", "value": "black"},
    {"name": "SecondYAxisTitleColor", "value": "black"},
    {"name": "XAxisTitleColor", "value": "black"},
    {"name": "YAxisTitleFontSize", "value": 18},
    {"name": "SecondYAxisTitleFontSize", "value": 17},
    {"name": "XAxisTitleFontSize", "value": 16},
    {"name": "BarWidth", "value": 30},
    {"name": "MarkShape", "value": "circle"},
    {"name": "MarkShapeSize", "value": "50"},
    {"name": "XAxisLabelLimit", "value": 0},
    {"name": "YRangemax", "value": 3.3000000000000003},
    {"name": "YRangemin", "value": null},
    {"name": "SecondYRangemax", "value": 0.002},
    {"name": "SecondYRangemin", "value": null},
    {"name": "BarColor", "value": "#ffd4a3"},
    {"name": "LineColor", "value": "#de3517"},
    {"name": "PointInnerColor", "value": "#f54e24"},
    {"name": "PointOuterColor", "value": "#f01919"},
    {"name": "SecondYAxisTitle", "value": "SUB DIVISION VALUE"},
    {"name": "LegendColumn", "value": 4},
    {"name": "LegendLabelBaseline", "value": "midivisionle"},
    {"name": "PointAngle", "value": 0},
    {"name": "LegendLabelColor", "value": "#000000"},
    {"name": "LegendLabelFontSize", "value": 14},
    {"name": "LegendLabelLimit", "value": 0},
    {"name": "LegendLabelOffset", "value": 25},
    {"name": "LegendLabelOpicity", "value": "1"},
    {"name": "LegendSymbolOpicity", "value": "0"},
    {"name": "YAxisTitleX", "value": -40},
    {"name": "BackgroundColor", "value": "#FFFFFF"},
    {"name": "XAxisGridOpacity", "value": 0},
    {"name": "YAxisGridOpacity", "value": 1},
    {"name": "XAxisGridColor", "value": "#d3d3d3"},
    {"name": "YAxisGridColor", "value": "#0d0c0c"},
    {
      "name": "BarLegendSymbol",
      "value": "M1.75,1.5V1H0V.5H1.75V0h1.5V.5H5V1H3.25v.5Z"
    },
    {"name": "LineLegendSymbol", "value": "square"},
    {"name": "LegendOrient", "value": "bottom"},
    {"name": "FontType", "value": "Calibri"},
    {"name": "TitleFontStyle", "value": "normal"},
    {"name": "TitleFontWeight", "value": "normal"},
    {"name": "SubtitleFontStyle", "value": "normal"},
    {"name": "SubtitleFontWeight", "value": "normal"},
    {"name": "AxisLabelFontStyle", "value": "bold"},
    {"name": "AxisLabelFontWeight", "value": "normal"},
    {"name": "AxisTitleFontStyle", "value": "bold"},
    {"name": "AxisTitleFontWeight", "value": "normal"},
    {"name": "LegendLabelFontStyle", "value": "normal"},
    {"name": "BackgroundCanvasColor", "value": "#FFFFFF"}
  ],
  "title": {
    "align": {"expr": "TitleAlign"},
    "anchor": {"expr": "TitleAnchor"},
    "baseline": {"expr": "TitleBaseline"},
    "color": {"expr": "TitleFontColor"},
    "dx": {"expr": "TitleDx"},
    "fontSize": {"expr": "TitleFontSize"},
    "limit": {"expr": "TitleLimit"},
    "offset": {"expr": "TitleOffset"},
    "subtitle": {"expr": "Subtitle"},
    "subtitleColor": {"expr": "SubTitileColor"},
    "subtitleFontSize": {"expr": "SubtitleFontSize"},
    "text": {"expr": "TitleText"}
  },
  "vconcat": [
    {
      "encoding": {
        "scale": {"domain": {"param": "brush"}},
        "sort": {"field": "id"},
        "x": {
          "axis": {
            "grid": true,
            "gridColor": {"expr": "XAxisGridColor"},
            "gridOpacity": {"expr": "XAxisGridOpacity"},
            "labelAngle": {"expr": "XAxisLabelAngle"},
            "labelColor": {"expr": "XAxisLabelColor"},
            "labelFontSize": {"expr": "XAxisLabelSize"},
            "labelLimit": {"expr": "XAxisLabelLimit"},
            "position": {"expr": "XAxisPostion"},
            "tickSize": {"expr": "XAxisTickSize"},
            "title": {"expr": "XAxisTitle"},
            "titleColor": {"expr": "XAxisTitleColor"}
          },
          "field": "description_data",
          "sort": {"field": "id"},
          "type": "nominal"
        }
      },
      "height": 200,
      "layer": [
        {
          "encoding": {
            "color": {
              "datum": "",
              "legend": {
                "columns": {"expr": "LegendColumn"},
                "labelBaseline": {"expr": "LegendLabelBaseline"},
                "labelColor": {"expr": "LegendLabelColor"},
                "labelFontSize": {"expr": "LegendLabelFontSize"},
                "labelLimit": {"expr": "LegendLabelLimit"},
                "labelOffset": {"expr": "LegendLabelOffset"},
                "labelOpacity": {"expr": "LegendLabelOpicity"},
                "orient": {"expr": "LegendOrient"},
                "symbolOpacity": {"expr": "LegendSymbolOpicity"},
                "symbolSize": {"expr": "BarLegendSymbolSize"},
                "symbolType": {"expr": "BarLegendSymbol"}
              },
              "scale": {"range": [{"expr": "BarColor"}]}
            },
            "y": {
              "axis": {
                "gridColor": {"expr": "YAxisGridColor"},
                "gridOpacity": {"expr": "YAxisGridOpacity"},
                "labelAngle": {"expr": "YAxisLabelAngle"},
                "labelColor": {"expr": "YAxisLabelColor"},
                "labelFontSize": {"expr": "YAxisLabelSize"},
                "labelLimit": {"expr": "YAxisLabelLimit"},
                "position": {"expr": "YAxisPostion"},
                "tickSize": {"expr": "YAxisTickSize"},
                "title": {"expr": "YAxisTitle"},
                "titleColor": {"expr": "YAxisTitleColor"},
                "titleFontSize": {"expr": "YAxisTitleFontSize"},
                "values": null
              },
              "field": "division",
              "scale": {
                "domainMax": {"expr": "YRangemax"},
                "domainMin": {"expr": "YRangemin"},
                "zero": false
              },
              "type": "quantitative"
            }
          },
          "mark": {
            "opacity": {"expr": "MarkOpacity"},
            "tooltip": true,
            "type": "bar",
            "width": {"expr": "BarWidth"}
          },
          "params": [
            {"name": "brush0", "select": {"encodings": ["x"], "type": "point"}}
          ]
        },
        {
          "encoding": {
            "color": {
              "datum": "",
              "legend": {"symbolStrokeColor": {"expr": "PointOuterColor"}},
              "scale": {"range": [{"expr": "PointInnerColor"}]}
            },
            "y": {
              "axis": {
                "format": ".3f", "tickCount":2,
                "grid": false,
                "gridColor": {"expr": "YAxisGridColor"},
                "gridOpacity": {"expr": "YAxisGridOpacity"},
                "labelColor": {"expr": "SecondYAxisLabelColor"},
                "labelFontSize": {"expr": "SecondYAxisLabelSize"},
       
                "orient": "right",
                "tickSize": {"expr": "SecondYAxisTickSize"},
                "title": {"expr": "SecondYAxisTitle"},
                "titleColor": {"expr": "SecondYAxisTitleColor"},
                "titleFontSize": {"expr": "SecondYAxisTitleFontSize"}
              },
              "field": "subdivision",
              "scale": {"domainMax": {"expr": "SecondYRangemax"}},
              "sort": null,
              "type": "quantitative"
            }
          },
          "mark": {
            "fill": "transparent",
            "filled": true,
            "point": {
              "angle": {"expr": "PointAngle"},
              "fill": {"expr": "PointInnerColor"},
              "shape": {"expr": "MarkShape"},
              "size": {"expr": "MarkShapeSize"},
              "stroke": {"expr": "PointOuterColor"}
            },
            "stroke": {"expr": "LineColor"},
            "tooltip": true,
            "type": "line"
          },
          "params": [
            {"name": "brush1", "select": {"encodings": ["x"], "type": "point"}}
          ]
        }
      ],
      "resolve": {
        "scale": {
          "color": "independent",
          "shape": "independent",
          "size": "independent",
          "y": "independent"
        }
      },
      "transform": [{"filter": {"param": "brush"}}],
      "view": {"fill": {"expr": "BackgroundColor"}},
      "width": "container"
    },
    {
      "encoding": {
        "color": {"value": "lightGray"},
        "x": {
          "axis": {"labels": false, "ticks": false, "title": ""},
          "field": "description_data",
          "sort": {"field": "id"},
          "type": "nominal"
        }
      },
      "height": 40,
      "mark": {"opacity": 0, "type": "area"},
      "params": [
        {
          "name": "brush",
          "select": {"encodings": ["x"], "translate": true, "type": "interval"}
        }
      ],
      "width": "container"
    }
  ],
  "view": {"stroke": "transparent"}
}

